# How to use facebook-connect invite friends iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

My app needs to invite friends from facebook conenct is this possibl e?
Any examples ?
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see it in the API, then it's probably not supported:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

You could load the page, http://www.facebook.com/invite.php in a UIWebView. The downside is the user would have to log in then.

You might want to contact the FB API folks and request it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can find info about using [FBC on the iPhone here](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone)

there are two modes you can use it in. One where your developer secret is in the phone app, if that makes you nervous you can proxy the authentication through your own server. FB developer site has the info along with programmer supported wikis